# Get client’s full last command (including key) from Redis

Tags: redis

Redis’s client list will give you the last command issued by client. It does not give you the key that last command was issued on. What I would like to get is the list key a client is doing `BLPOP` on.

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be nice to have that kind introspective functionality, it does not exist in Redis ATM. Instead you can try catching the command in-flight to understand what your client is doing.

The straightforward manner to do that is running [`MONITOR`](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) (from a different connection) before the client issues the `BLPOP` command to get that information. Note that `MONITOR` carries a performance impact so you should refrain from doing it in production.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for your response! I'm also considering adding pub/sub message along side of the push command to bettering logging/monitoring.

Comment: What if the command you want to inspect is an administrative command?

Comment: `MONITOR` also reports about admin commands (with passwords redacted, mostly)